# Change field name itertuple loop test

Tags: python, pandas

I need change field name ("newcolumn" ) :

```
def func(name_column):
    data = [1,2,3,4,5]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns[a,b,c,d])
    df["name_column"+"_1"]=df.name_column.shift(1)

    for row in df.itertuples():
          if row.a < row.(name_column+"_1"):
             return print('ok)
```

I tried `getattr(row,name_column+"_1")` but without succes.

Comment: You could try `df0[df0.index.hour.isin(range(8, 19))]]`, but no guarantee it will be faster

Comment: ok tku very much